# How to save a method name and names of all methods called inside that method when parsing a java file with ANTLR4?

Tags: java, parsing, listener, antlr4, method-invocation

I am working on a program that parses a Java file using the Java9 lexer and grammar from ANTLRs github. When parsing the file, I want to save each method name and the names of all methods called inside that method, in a `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`.

I use the listener pattern, where I use the method *exitMethodDeclaration* to get the method name and *exitMethodInvocation* to get the method invocations. The problem is that the two methods are invoked at different nodes in the parse tree, hence they take different context as argument. Therefore I am not able to call the method to get the invocations inside *exitMethodDeclaration*, to my knowledge. I attempted to build my own recursion, such that I could solve the type problem by passing methodDeclarationContext as argument to *exitMethodInvocation*. This would be very complex though, and I would like to use ANTLRs functionality.

With the code below, the hashSet for each method contains all method invocations for the **entire** file, and not just for the specific method.

```
private HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> methodCalls = new HashMap<>();
private HashSet<String> methodCallNames = new HashSet<>();

public void exitMethodDeclaration(Java9Parser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
        String methodName = ctx.methodHeader().methodDeclarator().identifier().getText();
        methodCalls.put(methodName, methodCallNames);
    }

public void exitMethodInvocation(Java9Parser.MethodInvocationContext ctx) {
    try {
        String m = ctx.methodName().identifier().getText();
        methodCallNames.add(m);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to collect nodes of different context type inside the same method, visit a subtree inside a listener/visitor method or other ideas are much welcome!

Comment: What if there is a anonymous class inside a method `foo`, and inside that anonymous class there is a method `bar` that calls `baz`. Do you count `baz` as one of the methods that `foo` calls too?

Comment: @Sweeper This is not something that I have considered, but thank you for bringing it up! Ideally I would count `baz` as one of the methods that `foo` calls, but any ideas on how to solve the problem without considering this, would also be much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest thing to write is on the visitor for `methodInvocation_lfno_primary` and `methodInvocation`, just traverse the parent chain till you get a `methodDeclarator` and then associate the method called with the method. Now, you also need to collect methods that have no calls, so you have to create an empty list of methods for all `methodDeclarator` if none exists. It'll take you 3-minutes to code this--very simple. It's not efficient, but the bigger issue is that you will find the java/java9 is not optimized--slow parsing.

Comment: I'd  not silently swallow exceptions like that: `catch (Exception e) {}`. If things go  wrong, you never know. At the very least log, or print  the error to the console: `catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Stack of ArrayLists.

Each time, you `enterMethodDeclaration`, push a new Empty ArrayList onto your Stack.

Each time you `enterMethodInvocation` (or `exit...` if you prefer), you can add the methodName to the ArrayList you have on stack.peek().

Whenever you `exitMethodDeclartation` stack.pop() you ArrayList, and it will have a list of all the method names you encountered in directly in that method call.  And, the method name is right there in the Context parameter of `exitMethodDeclaration`